# GCP Egress Cost from a GCP VM to Loadbalncer in the same region

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I would like to know the egress pricing in order to send the traffic from the GCP VM to GCP LB. Both services are in the same region.

Please see the below flow.

GCP VM ----> GCP LB

Essentially it's  egress traffic from one GCP Service to another GCP service.

Comment: Within the same zone $0. Zone to Zone in same region $.01 / GB. Region -> Region in same area (e.g. US) $0.01 / GB. Region to Region in different areas (e.g. US -> Europe) $0.12 / GB. These prices are without CDN. HTTPS Load Balancers usually run at the edge closest to the customer. Egress from LB to customer is $0.12 / GB

Comment: Here is an excellent video to watch from Google on pricing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2OG1w6bGFo

Answer (score 2):

This documentation should tell you all you need to know [Network Service Tiers pricing](https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers/pricing)

If not, please be aware that internal network traffic inside a project is free, only outbound traffic from your project to the internet needs to be payed.

If your LB is an internal one, there should be no cost.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my case, LB is a regional one and provisioned in us-west1 region. The VM also provisioned in same the region. We have a uses case in application workflow to send traffic from GCP VM to GCP external load balancer. 
As per the documentation "Egress to a different Google Cloud Platform service within the same region using an external IP address or an internal IP address, except for Cloud Memory store for Redis, Cloud Filestore, and Cloud SQL is no charge"

if I'm not wrong, there won't be any charges if the above statement is correct.

Comment: Could you put the link of the documentation? That could be interresting for other people wondering the same thing as you :)

Comment: @night-cgold - Please let me know your thoughts on this

Comment: Not sure, is the LB included inside those services, and even if the traffic to the lb is free, is it the same for the answer passing through the lb? Did you take a look at the video in the comment of John Hanley?

Comment: There would some charge for processing the requests at LB based on the forwarding rules